# fail2ban как правильно банить по порту

Tags: iptables, asterisk

Есть такая история: Астериск в локальной сети и к нему проброшен порт 5060. Ломится ко мне брутфорсер, но вот в логах моя белая ІР+рандом порт (я так понял что NAT). Соответственно забанить ІР не могу т.к полностью отрежу  Клиентов телефонии от астериска. И вот вопрос как правильно настроить Fail2ban на бан порта? Как банит он по ІР понятно а вот о порте не пойму никак... Либо направьте на правильное решение данного вопроса. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Включите лог событий безопасности в logger.conf

```
security_log => security
```

и сконфигурируйте fail2ban для работы по файлу, указанному в этой директиве (в данном случае — security_log). Там должны быть реальные адреса брутфорсеров.

Comment: [2019-12-08 23:40:23] SECURITY[41525] res_security_log.c: SecurityEvent="ChallengeResponseFailed",EventTV="2019-12-08T23:40:23.956+0200",Severity="Error",Service="PJSIP",EventVersion="1",AccountID="<unknown>",SessionID="2328619201",LocalAddress="IPV4/UDP/192.168.41.7/5060",RemoteAddress="IPV4/UDP/xxx.xx.xx.xx/5072",Challenge="1575841223/59beb3c1726333836ddec338a94f7a59",Response="6757a71fb4044cf1d8825fcf2ecbb8a9",ExpectedResponse=""

Comment: Вот такое мне приходит - xxx - мой ІР внешний

Comment: Значит, смотрите, каким образом у вас организован проброс порта и делайте так, чтобы там не подменялся source address. С этим я вам ничем не помогу. Вообще-то это необычно, что он подменяется.

Comment: ничего странного нет - это маскарадинг называется)

Comment: ну хорошо - раз нет реальных IP тогда как можно это сделать? мне хоть идею дать - а тестами и настройкой заниматся буду сам.

Comment: Ну, не знаю. Маскарадинг, который DNAT, например, тот не подменяет source IP. Поэтому он и _D_NAT. Что касается идей "как сделать" — повторюсь: настроить проброс пакетов таким образом, чтобы он не менял source IP. Ну или выставить астериск в интернет с реальным адресом. Они всегда есть, просто кто-то не хочет платить, а другие не хотят менять сложившуюся инфраструктуру.